# PHP storing a two dimension array from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a simple question. I have an array that has two columns (id, name) that is a result of a MySQL query. I want to store the result of the query into a array variable so i can access each element when i need to.

I am able to store a one dimension array like the following:

```
    $array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row['name'];
    }
```

How can I store and access a two dimensional array? Also is it best to use a for loop or while loop to store these?

Comment: the below answers are fine, but sometimes you may want `$array[$row['id']] = $row;` if you want to pick thinks out of the array based on your index\valuie in mysql

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Why has this been down voted? It might be an entry level php question, but we all have different experience levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

To access your results you can do this:

```
$firstResultRow = $array[0];
$firstResultName = $array[0]['id'];
$firstResultName = $array[0]['name'];
```

This will tell you if a particular row exists:

```
if(isset($array[$x])) {
    $aRow = $row[$x];
    // do stuff with $aRow;
}
```

This will give you a row count for your array:

```
$rowCount = count($array);
```

This will set up a loop through your array:

```
foreach($array as $index => $row) {
    $id = $row['id']
    $name = $row['name'];
    // $index will have the array index of the current row. 0 -> $rowCount - 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I access each index?

Comment: Added some more details @kkmoslehpour

Comment: I have tried to use the `foreach` to echo the values, however, i am getting " Illegal string offset 'name' " have you seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Don't specifically store the index of `$row` but rather store the whole row.

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Then $array will have the following structure:

```
$array = [
    [
       'id'=> ...,
       'name' => ...,
    ],
    ...
];
```

To initially access all of the results from `[mysqli_fetch_assoc][1]` you will want to use the while loop like you are, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will continue to output results until it doesn't have any more data.  Then at that point `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will return `NULL`.  This will signal to your while loop to stop iterating.

Then to access variables inside of your `$array`, I recommend using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

You could then do:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  do something with $row['name'] or $row['id']
}
```

You could also use a for loop, but it takes more work IMO.  Compare the above with this alternative:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   $row = $array[$i];
   do something with $row['name'] or $row['id']
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, and how can I access each index?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour Hey I updated my answer to provide a more complete explanation and also provided some options as far as accessing the values.